# Create or update child model in ASP.NET MVC/Entify Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a video model with a collection of tags that I want to create

```
public class Video{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  etc.
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

I have a standard generated controller action that looks like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Video video)
  {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Videos.Add(video);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
  }
```

The model binding seems to work correctly, I get a new Video with the desired values, and a collection of tags. (primary keys, 1,7, 34 etc)

However with this method, the new video is not bound to existing tags, it is always created new ones.

Is there a automatic way that if the tag with the supplied Id exist, it is not created a new one, however it is only created a relation to the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the supply tags via checkboxes on video create page, and then if user cannot find related then he can create a new one via the same name tag on textboxes. here is an example for updating checkboxes i got it from asp.net mvc site

```
private void UpdateInstructorCourses(string[] selectedCourses, Instructor instructorToUpdate)
{
if (selectedCourses == null)
{
    instructorToUpdate.Courses = new List<Course>();
    return;
}
var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedCourses);
var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>
    (instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));
foreach (var course in db.Courses)
{
    if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID.ToString()))
    {
        if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
        {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses.Add(course);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
        {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses.Remove(course);
        }
    }
}
}
```

my opinion it's best way to do it, the hashset also include new tags if you created textbox with same name.

here is the full tutorial

http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I'm gonna have 100's of tags, checkboxes isn't gonna cut it. I'm using a textbox with jqueryui's autocomplete and multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
 var newtags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (var tag in video.Tags)
        {
            var t = db.Tags.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name.ToLower() == tag.Name.ToLower());
            if (t != null)
            {
                newtags.Add(t);
                continue;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag.Name))
            {
                newtags.Add(tag);
            }
        }
 video.Tags = newtags;
```

This way the tags are checked with the database, and if they exist, I add the existing tag to a temporary list, if itdon't exist I add the new tag to the temporary list.

Then reassign all tags to be the new list, some new, some old.

New tags are then created, and bound to the video, the others are only bound.

Not sure if this is the best way though.